# How do I make "thick cooked rhubarb"

Tags: cookies, rhubarb

I'm looking at a 1960's Betty Crocker cookie recipe that calls for "1 cup thick cooked rhubarb". What sort of preparation does this imply? Baking? Stewing? Should I add sugar?

For reference, here's a copy of the recipe for reference: http://recipe-finder.com/#!/recipe/16473076193787340525

Comment: Copying recipe content is not considered copyright infringement, as they do not meet some criteria (I think it was creative effort or such). However, you are not allowed to reproduce a printed recipe including layout and pictures. As for the question itself, throwing rhubarb into the pan and cooking until it is softened but not completely dissolved will give you a thick consistency. Not making this an answer, as I have no idea if this is what the recipe understands under this term.

Comment: The very thought of cooked rhubarb without sugar added made my cheeks contract involuntarily! I would put it in a saucepan with sugar and the least amount of water you can manage to stop the pan boiling dry, and simmer it gently until the rhubarb is all broken up.

Comment: Could it be possible there is a typo in the recipe? Maybe it is meant to read "Thick, cooked rhubarb" meaning that you need to cook thick stalks instead of thin ones (I would think the thicker ones would hold up to cooking better, holding onto a bit of structure)?

Comment: @webtina: Not a typo--I've got the recipe out of my copy of the Betty Crocker Cooky Book. The above link is just one I found for reference.

Comment: @rumtscho: Wow, I had no idea recipe content was not covered under copyright. That seems...dicey. In any case, I'll rephrase to avoid slandering that poster.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to make a guess, thick cooked rhubarb would be chunks of rhubarb cooked in a sugar syrup that is thickened. (Kind of like cherry pie filling, which comes in cans.)

Here's what I would do to simulate this:

1. cut some chunks of rhubarb in a size that you think you would like in a pie or cobbler.
2. Add some water (at least a cup) and the rhubarb to a saucepan.  Add some sugar (about a cup) Cook on medium low heat until the sugar is dissolved and the sauce is boiled down to a thick syrup.
3. Let the mix cool, or refrigerate, and then move along with your recipe.

Comment: The real question here is how much sugar you have to put into the rhubarb. The cookie recipe already calls for a fair amount, so I'm guessing there's some room for flexibility here: you can put less in the rhubarb and have a more tart cookie if you want.